# Is it possible to differentiate two objects without using unique object properties?

Tags: javascript

I want to create two objects with no differentiating properties and determine the difference between them, but every method I've tried has failed.

```js
//this results in false x2
function Special() {
}
var objects = {};
objects.obj1 = {};
objects.obj2 = {};
objects.obj2.constructor = Special;
for (property in objects) {
  if (objects[property] instanceof Special) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

```js
//this results in false x2
function Special() {
  return {};
}
var objects = {};
objects.obj1 = {};
objects.obj2 = new Special();
for (property in objects) {
  if (objects[property] instanceof Special) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

```js
//this hangs the page
function Special() {
  this = {};
}
var objects = {};
objects.obj1 = {};
objects.obj2 = new Special();
for (property in objects) {
  if (objects[property] instanceof Special) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to differentiate two objects without using unique object properties? Why or why not?

For clarification, I'm trying to avoid this:

```
var objects = {
    obj1 : {
       type : 'normal'
    },
    obj2 : {
       type : 'special'
    }
}
```

**Context:**

I'm working with a "directory" type data structure and to keep the structure as simple as possible, I'd like some properties to just be child directories, while other properties are items in the directory, however since both child directories and items could be objects, and we wouldn't want to restrict items from having their own "type" property, Im looking for a different way to differentiate - I thought constructor types might be a solution.

So, I'm trying to ultimately have a data structure like this:

```
var directory = {
    handlers : { //child directory
        button1 : function() {} //item
    },
    selectors : { //child directory
        button1 : '#button-1' //item
    },
    title : 'hello world', //item
    data : { //item
        property1 : 1
    }
}
```

Where I don't need to add layers of complexity to differentiate the objects which represent items and directories.

Comment: `My goal is for one of the logs to be true.`I hope you'll excuse me, but I don't believe that's your actual goal. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @vlaz Are you saying "you're asking about X solution, but what you really want is to solve Y problem"?

Comment: OK I think I get it now, let me see if I do - you have two objects, let's say `var a = {name: "bob"}` and `var b = {name: "bob"}` and you want to find out if different, even if they both have the same data. Is that correct?

Comment: what this `function Special() {  this = {}; }`  is supposed to mean when it is used as a constructor? It has no effect.

Comment: @vlaz Correct. Im working with a "directory" type data structure and to keep the structure as simple as possible, I'd like some properties to just be child directories, while other properties are items in the directory, however since both child directories and items could be objects, and we wouldn't want to restrict items from having their own "type" property, Im looking for a different way to differentiate - I thought constructor types might be a solution.

Comment: Just use `a === b`?

Comment: @Oriol sorry, I tried to keep my question as simple as possible but its clear more context is needed. See my above comment, which Ill be editing into the question.

Comment: What Oriol said would help - two objects will only be the same if they are the exact _same_ object - `a === a` will return `true` but `a === b` won't, since they are _different objects_.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear what you want, and your code doesn't make much sense. The 2nd `Special` function declaration is hoisted so in both parts `Special` is the second one, `this = {}` is a `ReferenceError`, a `constructor` property does not determine inheritance and will be ignored by `instanceof`.

Comment: @Oriol Yeah sorry. I made an edit giving an example for the context. Does that make what I'm trying to do clear?

Comment: No. I still don't get what are you trying to differentiate and why the current results are unexpected.

Comment: Well, maybe do you want to check if an object was returned by the `Special` constructor?

Comment: @Oriol Did you see my edit about directory data structure? I thought the context would at least make it clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I saw it but I still don't get what you are trying to differentiate, and what you mean with "constructor type".

Comment: @Oriol Maybe it's impossible, which is why you'd be confused about it. By constructor type, I meant as in `obj1 instanceof Directory; // true` - I was interested in using that method to differentiate between two objects to know if the object is a sub directory or an item in my directory structure. But according to the answer below I can't do it, so never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to differentiate two objects without using unique object properties? Why or why not?

No, you can't. Since javascript is dynamically typed, you can modify object properties on the fly:

```
function Friend(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Friend.prototype.get = function(){
    return this.name;
}

var pete = new Friend('Pete');

pete.get(); //'Pete'
pete instanceof Friend; //true

pete.get = function(){
    return 'hacked!';
}

pete.get(); //'hacked!'
pete.get; //Function...
pete instanceof Friend; //true

delete pete.name;
delete pete.get;

pete.name; //undefined
pete.get; //undefined
pete instanceof Friend; //still true
```

So, instanceof now says pete **is a** Friend, and then adheres to the Friend's interface. However, pete now has no name and no get function attached to it.

The only way to know if two objects have the very same properties, or at least the same collection of functions, is to iterate over them and check manually. And, if two objects happen to have the same properties in a given moment, lately that can change.

The underlying problem is that, in javascript, there are nothing like a classes: there are only plain objects. Language constructs like new, constructor or instanceof were put into the language to reassemble Java, but they really doesn't fit at all with [delegate prototype inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), and instanceof and constructor properties can be [broken in many ways](https://tsherif.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/constructors-are-bad-for-javascript/).

Usually, [Object.isPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) is a better approach to check if one object inherits from another (while are different methods that check different things), since, well, even if you add or delete properties to an object, it will default to its prototype as long as you don't mess with the prototype itself.